# Concatenate variable in python

Tags: python, concatenation, kivy

I made a variable `colonne` which returns the number of the column.

I'm trying to put it in the selection of my function like that:

```
self.ids.image+colonne+_1
```

here is my complete view:

```
Button:
    on_press: root.click_colonne(1)
    pos: 25,25
    size: 100, 500
    opacity:0
Image:
    source: 'image.png'
    pos: 0,0
    size: 150,150
    id: image1_1
Image:
    source: 'image.png'
    pos: 0,100
    size: 150,150
    id: image1_2
Image:
    source: 'image.png'
    pos: 0,200
    size: 150,150
    id: image1_3
Image:
    source: 'image.png'
    pos: 0,300
    size: 150,150
    id: image1_4
Image:
    source: 'image.png'
    pos: 0,400
    size: 150,150
    id: image1_5



Button:
    on_press: root.click_colonne(2)
    pos: 125,25
    size: 100, 500
    opacity:0
Image:
    source: 'image.png'
    pos: 100,0
    size: 150,150
    id: image2_1
Image:
    source: 'image.png'
    pos: 100,100
    size: 150,150
    id: image2_2
Image:
    source: 'image.png'
    pos: 100,200
    size: 150,150
    id: image2_3
Image:
    source: 'image.png'
    pos: 100,300
    size: 150,150
    id: image2_4
Image:
    source: 'image.png'
    pos: 100,400
    size: 150,150
    id: image2_5
```

and here is my complete function:

```
def click_colonne(self, colonne):
    if self.ids.image+colonne+_1.source == "image.png":
        self.ids.image+colonne+_1.source = "image_rouge.png"
    elif self.ids.image+colonne+_2.source == "image.png":
        self.ids.image+colonne+_2.source = "image_rouge.png"
    elif self.ids.image+colonne+_3.source == "image.png":
        self.ids.image+colonne+_3.source = "image_rouge.png"
    elif self.ids.image+colonne+_4.source == "image.png":
        self.ids.image+colonne+_4.source = "image_rouge.png"
    elif self.ids.image+colonne+_5.source == "image.png":
        self.ids.image+colonne+_5.source = "image_rouge.png"
```

here is the error

```
File "main.py", line 36
self.ids.image+colonne+_5.source = "image_rouge.png"
^
SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
```

Can someone give me the correct syntax?

Comment: What is the error you’re getting? Also what is `_1`

Comment: @Jaba i added it to the post

Comment: @Antoine553 what is the meaning of `self.ids.image+colonne+_5.source `?

Comment: @Jaba the _1 is because of the id of the image which is image1_1 (for column=1 number=1)

Comment: [Format strings](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/format) will probably be much easier to read over raw concatenation.

Comment: to me it looks like you are trying to add things which are not possible to add… what prints if you find out the types of your variables, like `print(type(self.ids))` etc for every piece of variable in that line?

Comment: You simply can't concatenate things together to make a variable name. The better way is to use lists.

Comment: @eyllanesc I'm trying to make `self.ids.image1_1.source` which select the attribute source of image1_1 but with the first 1 comming from the variable colonne

Comment: Also, use a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) or a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) to clean up all of that repetition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concatenation does not generate that the name of the variable is formed, you are only adding its values and that can not be done on the left side of the operator =. A better option is to build the name as a string and use it through the ids dictionary

```
self.ids["image{}_{}".format(colone, 5)].source = "image_rouge.png"
```

Another solution is

```
getattr(self.ids, "image{}_{}".format(colone, 5)).source = "image_rouge.png"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution valid in Python 3.6 and later :

```
def click_colonne(self, colonne):
    for i in range(1, 6):
        if self.ids[f"image{colone}_{i}"].source == "image.png":
            self.ids[f"image{colone}_{i}"].source = "image_rouge.png"
            break
```

The `f""` replace the `.format()` function allowing you to add the variable inside the quotes.